# Formula Field To Calculate Detail Total

Tags: formula, acumatica

I have two DAC's, POReceipt, and POReceiptLine. I want to add a field to POReceipt that aggregates the total cost of the POReceiptLines.

Is there a way to do this with attributes? I Can I us PXFormula, or something of this sort?

The field should be the sum of the Receipt Line Costs.

Comment: I don't have time to provide a tailored answer but it's a common question. I'd think you could find a useful answer in other questions like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087790/how-to-sum-multiple-fields-in-acumatica-pxformula

Answer (score 3):

Calculating Aggregate Values With PXUnboundFormula

```
using PX.Data;
namespace PX.Objects.PO
{
public sealed class POReceiptExt : PXCacheExtension<POReceipt>
{
    [PXDBDecimal]
    [PXDefault("0.0", PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Total Cost ")]
    public decimal? TotalCost { get; set; }
    public abstract class totalCost : IBqlField
    {
    }
}
public sealed class POReceiptLineExt : PXCacheExtension<POReceiptLine>
{
    [PXDBDecimal]
    [PXDefault("0.0", PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Line Cost")]
    [PXUnboundFormula(typeof(POReceiptLineExt.lineCost), typeof(SumCalc<POReceiptExt.totalCost>))]
    public decimal? LineCost { get; set; }
    public abstract class lineCost : IBqlField
    {
    }
  }
}
```

[Calculating Values of UI Elements](https://help-2018r1.acumatica.com/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=1d25dc74-747c-4d44-8ad9-033e5a476b6f)